# Not able to understand the logic behind the code which is an optimisation problem of generating prime numbers between two given numbers

Tags: c++, stl

Peter wants to generate some prime numbers for his cryptosystem. Help him! Your task is to generate all prime numbers between two given numbers!

Input
The input begins with the number t of test cases in a single line (t<=10). In each of the next t lines there are two numbers m and n (1 <= m <= n <= 1000000000, n-m<=100000) separated by a space.

Output
For every test case print all prime numbers p such that m <= p <= n, one number per line, test cases separated by an empty line.

Example
Input:

```
2
1 10
3 5
```

Output:

```
2
3
5
7

3
5
```

Warning: large Input/Output data, be careful with certain languages (though most should be OK if the algorithm is well designed)

I looked up on google to find an optimasation solution for the above problem and here's the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <set>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    vector<int> primes;
    primes.push_back(2);

    for (int i = 3; i <= 32000; i+=2) {
        bool isprime = true;
        int cap = sqrt(i) + 1;

        vector<int>::iterator p;
        for (p = primes.begin(); p != primes.end(); p++) {
            if (*p >= cap) break;
            if (i % *p == 0) {
                isprime = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (isprime) primes.push_back(i);
    }

    int T,N,M;

    cin >> T;

    for (int t = 0; t < T; t++) {
        if (t) cout << endl;

        cin >> M >> N;
        if (M < 2) M = 2;

        int cap = sqrt(N) + 1;

        set<int> notprime;
        notprime.clear();

        vector<int>::iterator p;
        for (p = primes.begin(); p != primes.end(); p++) {

            if (*p >= cap) break;
            int start;

            if (*p >= M) start = (*p)*2;
            else start = M + ((*p - M % *p) % *p); //not able to understand this logic.

            for (int j = start; j <= N; j += *p) {
                notprime.insert(j);
            }
        }

        for (int i = M; i <= N; i++) {
            if (notprime.count(i) == 0) {
                cout << i << endl;
            }
        }

    }
    return 0;
}
```

I am not able to understand the above code. Please, help me in understanding it. I am just not getting the logic behind this program(I know STL, just want to understand the logic).

Comment: Round down M to previous multiple of `*p`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its pretty simple really. You precalculate all primes that exists in your range. Then for each multiple of prime, except first, you mark number as "not prime".

Line you marked just calculates first occurence of particular prime's multiple in range M to N.

Edit: More explanations.

This method finds primes by first searching for all non-primes. What is left is primes.

To do so on first step it calculates all "small" primes. Then for each small prime it marks all its multiples that fit in target range. To do so, you need first calculate first occurence of this prime in your range - this is what "start" variable is. Basically it is first multiple of prime that >= M.
When yo have "start" you simply mark all multiples by adding prime to current number until you reach N.

If you still confused about what and how "start" is calculated try to think about how you would find "x" such that it is "x = A * y" and "x >= M" where you know A and M, but don't know "y".

Also I think there probably error in this algorithm. Because it should complete this cycle for each value in "nonprime" set. But may be it doesn't matter if first unaccounted prime multiple always > N.

Comment: Ohkay but still not able to get how that expression came.  Can you expain that whole for loop(in which the marked statement is) in detail.

Comment: Expanded explanatin a bit